# Angular material nav bar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I tried to run this simple demo in my app:

http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Kgdvgd?editors=1010#0

Do in `View1.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rfApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
});
```

View1.html

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
        <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">Page One</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">Page Two</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
        <!-- these require actual routing with ui-router or ng-route, so they won't work in the demo
        <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="app.page4" name="page4">Page Four</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#page5" name="page5">Page Five</md-nav-item>
        -->
    </md-nav-bar>
    <div class="ext-content">
        External content for `<span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>`
    </div>
</md-content>
```

And get:

[image]

Comment: Codepen is work anyway. Are you sure you include angular material css in the header?

Comment: @digit Yes, all other elements working

Comment: @digit all scripts loaded correctly and this is whole my code:( what is wrong :(

Comment: i use https://github.com/angular/angular-seed template

Comment: It seems to be related to css issue. You try to include external css first.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in my angular and angular-material version. When I changed angular to `1.5.9` and angular-material to `1.0.0` it started working